# What is the correct way to set up an https proxy within meta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy, scrapy

I've created a script using scrapy implementing proxies within it to fetch content from a website. The script appears to be working correctly. The site I'm trying to grab data from is `https://www.zillow.com/miami-fl-33166/`.

Since this is an `https` site and I'm using `https` proxies, I've set up a proxy like the following:

```
request.meta['proxy'] = 'https://123.200.20.242:58847'
```

***However, when I execute the script today after accidentally changing `https` to `http` like the following, I could notice that the script still works.***

```
request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://123.200.20.242:58847'
```

This is how I've implemented proxies within middleware:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    request.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    request.meta['proxy'] = 'https://123.200.20.242:58847'
    # request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://123.200.20.242:58847'
```

And this is the reference:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'customized_bot.proxy_middleware.ProxiesMiddleware': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
}
```

> What is right way to set up `https` proxies within meta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of `https` proxy is not any different from using `http` proxy. You simply need to change the proxy address from using `http` to using `https`. See this article on [zyte.com](https://support.zyte.com/support/solutions/articles/22000219743-using-a-custom-proxy-in-a-scrapy-spider) on how to use `https` proxy. To summarize, you can:

1. Pass the proxy via `meta` object when making a `scrapy.Request`
2. Setup a custom `scrapy middleware` that adds the proxy header to each `scrapy Request`.
   Mode details provided at [zyte.com](https://support.zyte.com/support/solutions/articles/22000219743-using-a-custom-proxy-in-a-scrapy-spider)

To answer your question, `http` and `https` proxy can be used interchangeably to scrape `http` and `https` urls.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about the `https` proxy suggested in that article.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Okay, understood. Now, the question (`already mentioned in my post`) is, does it really matter whether I pass `http` or `https` proxy via meta even when I scrape data from an `https` site, because they both appears to be working interchangeably. Thanks.

Comment: It does not matter what proxy type you use. Both ```http``` and ```https``` proxy can be used to scrape ```http``` and ```https``` urls and vice versa.